# asp.net client side timeout issue

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, session-timeout

we are using a jquery tree in our asp.net mvc application and have forms authentication configured. A session timeout for 10 minutes is configured. The problem is if the user keeps interacting with the tree for more than 10 minutes the session times out when a request goes to the server.

Kind of critical issue since the user was interacting with the application and got logged out.

What could be a good solution to this issue?

Comment: How about timely, Session Keep alive pings to server...

Comment: Use a client-side timer whose value is submitted on a server request - have it reset with client-side actions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Extend the session timeout setting in IIS (maybe set it to 20 or 30 minutes to give the user enough time)
2. Use some periodical AJAX calls from the client side that just tell your server the user is still active.